# OAuth2.0 авторизация

Tags: java, rest, oauth

[image: img]
<sub>(источник: [internet-technologies.ru](http://www.internet-technologies.ru/uploads/articles/201311/potok-veb-servera-270413.jpg))</sub>

Прошу извинения, за возможно глупый вопрос, но у меня возникла проблема с пониманием OAuth, скажите пожалуйста почему во всех туториалах, архитектура OAuth изображена таким образом что, Сервер ресурсов, и сервер авторизации, это две разные сущности, это принципиально так, или можно их объединить в одну?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

данный протокол позволяет одному приложению(сервису) выдать права на доступ к ресурсам пользователя на других сервисах. Ресурсы могут быть больше одного. Получая права, ты сразу имеешь доступ ко всем сервисам без авторизации.

Например, ты логинишься вконтакте и получаешь доступ к сервисам, как фотографии, видеозаписи, аудиозаписи и т.д.

Дополнительно [тут](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-31) можно почитать

В Принципе, сервер ресурсов и авторизации могут быть на одной машине(сервере), но это плохая практика и плохо масштабируема